# How do I fix the white screen after I "npm Start" my react app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, package.json

So ive created a e-commerce website using react and it was working perfectly. however and I accidentally deleted the packagej.son file I've recently recovered it and its exactly how it was before, however now whenever I try to run the app I get a white screen. The app is compiling with no errors and seems to be working fine. and I've tried everything and have been debugging for hours. Please help me.

if the question is bad please dont slate me im new to stack overflow.

**Here is my package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "ecommerce-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-fast-marquee": "^1.3.5",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.7.1",
    "react-image-zoom": "^1.3.1",
    "react-rating-stars-component": "^2.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
`
```

**here is my App.js:**

```
`import React from 'react';
`import './App.css';`
`import {  BrowserRouter,Routes,Route } from 'react-router-dom';
`import Layout from './components/Layout';
`import Home from './pages/Home';`
`import About from './pages/About';`
`import Contact from './pages/Contact';`

`import OurStore from './pages/OurStore';``

`import Blogs from './pages/Blogs';`
`import CompareProduct from './pages/CompareProduct';`
`import Wishlist from './pages/Wishlist';`
`import Login from './pages/Login';
`import Cart from './pages/Cart';``
`import Forgotpassword from './pages/Forgotpassword';`
`import Signup from './pages/Signup';`
 import Resetpassword from './pages/Resetpassword';
 import SingleBlog from './pages/SingleBlog';
 import PrivacyPolicy from './pages/PrivacyPolicy';
 import RefundPolicy from './pages/RefundPolicy';
 import ShippingPolicy from './pages/ShippingPolicy';
 import TermsOfService from './pages/TermsOfService';
 import SingleProduct from './pages/SingleProduct';
 import Checkout from './pages/Checkout';
 function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element= {<Layout />}>
        <Route index element={<Home />}/>
        <Route path="about" element={<About />}/>
        <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />}/>
        <Route path="store" element={<OurStore />}/>
        <Route path="/product/:id" element={<SingleProduct />}/>
        <Route path="blogs" element={<Blogs />}/>
        <Route path="/blog:id" element={<SingleBlog />}/>
        <Route path="compare-product" element={<CompareProduct />}/>
        <Route path="wishlist" element={<Wishlist />}/>
        <Route path="login" element={<Login />}/>
        <Route path="cart" element={<Cart />}/>
        <Route path="checkout" element={<Checkout />}/>
        <Route path="forgot-password" element={<Forgotpassword />}/>
        <Route path="sign-up" element={<Signup />}/>
        <Route path="reset-password" element={<Resetpassword />}/>
        <Route path="privacy-policy" element={<PrivacyPolicy />}/>
        <Route path="refund-policy" element={<RefundPolicy />}/>
        <Route path="shipping-policy" element={<ShippingPolicy />}/>
        <Route path="terms-and-conditions" element={<TermsOfService />}/>

      </Route>
      </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}`

export default App;
```

**here is my index.js:**

```
`import React from 'react';
 import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
 import App from './App';

 const container = document.getElementById('root');
 const root = createRoot(container);
`
`root.render(<App />);``
```

**Heres my output:**
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MABA.png)

`

what ive tried:

1. changing "homepage" in the package.json to my git repository and localhost:3000
2. run build whenever i changed something in the j,son
3. tried changing the default localhost port
4. changed BrowserRouter to HashRouter
   but none gets rid of the white screen.

Answer (score 1):

Without more context or error logs, it is difficult to determine the root cause of the issue, but here are a few steps you can try:

1. Check the component imported in `SingleBlog` and `SingleProduct` if they are correctly imported and working as expected.
2. Check the Route path values and make sure they match the component file names.
3. You can try adding a catch-all Route component to see if there's an issue with the routing itself, like so:

   `<Route path="*" element={<div>Page not found</div>} />`
4. Try clearing your browser cache to see if it helps.

If none of these steps work, you may want to try adding some debugging information in the form of console.log statements to see where the issue may be originating from.

Answer (score 0):

It works now! turns out is was that my  tags got  to have "to", for anyone that faces the same issue. add  to all of your Link tags if  your console.log says "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')" or "the above error occurred in the link component react "